# How to list contents of another directory without being in it?

Tags: unix, terminal, directory

Here is what my directory looks like:

```
Test ----
        |
        |----One
        |
        |----Two
```

I am attempting to list the contents of Two while still being in One and I am not able to do so.

I have tried this command (as seen in a other post) : "ls Test/" and it says No such file or directory. I have also tried ls Test/Two/ and it still does not work.

Comment: Be aware Unix is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in One and you want to list the contents of Two, you should go up to the parent directory using `..`:

`ls ../Two`

`../` will place you in the Test directory, from there, you can go to Two with no problem. If you have more depth levels, just add more `../` to go up one directory each time, but mind which is your current directory when running the command.

Comment: You might add the alternative of entering the complete path starting with `/`, or something like `$HOME/Test/Two".

Comment: Thank you for your input, this helped me greatly and got it working as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

what does this command provide you in terminal.

ls -al Test  //a flag is used for hidden file